# Why is that the following indexOf isn't matching the given substring?

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through an array of URLS. If the url has the substring `/w/400/h/400/g` I want it to run some code. However, it never runs:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < this.leancloudFiles.length; i++) {
    console.log('LEAN:', this.leancloudFiles[i])
    if (this.leancloudFiles[i].indexOf('/w/400/h/400/g') !== -1) {
      console.log('DOESNT LOG')
    } else {
      // something else
    } 
  }
```

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

The log of `LEAN:` is:

> http://vrcam-10065475.image.myqcloud.com/7d7a940af736a26240a1.jpg?imageView2/2/w/800/h/800/q/100/format/jpg
>
> http://vrcam-10065475.image.myqcloud.com/a16bb57c6f1d4cc3eb14.jpg?imageView2/2/w/400/h/400/q/100/format/jpg

Comment: @Archer — No. That's ``\``

Comment: Lol.  Oh dear.  Nothing to see here.

Comment: this one is easy `"g" != "q"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't match because it the substring just doesn't appear in the strings.

`indexOf('/w/400/h/400/g')` ends the pattern with a lowercase G, but the URLs have lowercase Qs there.